# Meaning of “act on” in the context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrasal-verbs

Based on the definition in most dictionaries, “act on” means to behave and use someone’s advice or reason for doing something else.

However, I came across the phrasal verb in my biology textbook, and the sentence is

> - Myosin **acts on microfilaments** to produce muscle movements.

Does it mean that **Myosin** receives messages from **microfilaments** to produce movements? Or **Myosin** triggers **Microfilaments** to produce muscle movements?

Comment: You might have been looking up the phrasal verb *act on* which has a specific meaning as a single phrasal verb, but does not have the same meaning as the simple conjunction of the verb *act* and the preposition *on*.

Answer (score 1):

There are two completely different meanings of the phrase "act on".

As you say, "act on" can mean to take someone's advice and put it into action. Like, "Bob told me to invest in the stock market and I ACTED ON his advice by buying 100 shares of Foobar Corporation."

But "act on" can also be used to mean that one object or substance affects another. Like, "This cleaning product ACTS ON tough stains", in this example presumably meaning that it cleans them. The examples I can think of off the top of my head all involve chemical action, but I wouldn't swear that that's the only context.

Comment: *I'm going to act on the stage?* ;) Or, to keep up with your context, *this massage will act on your muscles.*

Comment: @JasonBassford "Act on stage": a third definition of the word. Thanks for bringing it up, I didn't think of that. "Massage will act on your muscles": Yes, good non-chemical example. Thanks.